# WCF The request failed with http status 400 bad request. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: http://localhost/MyService.svc/mex

Tags: c#, wcf

I ran into an interesting error this morning and didn't find any useful help online so I wanted to document my solution somewhere.

I have a WCF service being hosted in IIS that exposes a bunch of functions for interacting with a database (INSERTS, UPDATES, DELETES and SELECTS). I also have a website that consumes this service. All was working wonderfully for many weeks until I had to make some fairly drastic database changes last night.

Some of my tables had to get renamed, new ones were created, fields were added and removed on many tables, relationships were torn down and recreated in other places, etc. Luckily, I have scripts that automatically generate the database-related code (including the SQL statements) so all I really needed to do was update the web service to use the new schemas and Visual Studio told me where all those places were as they showed up as compiler errors.

Many of the errors were resolved by simply renaming type and property references to match the new schema. I also added some methods to expose the INSERT, UPDATE and SELECT functions of the new tables. Eventually, I got it all compiling and everything seemed good.

However, when I went to my website code to update the service reference, I was getting a `The request failed with http status 400 bad request. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: http://localhost/MyService.svc/mex` error. Nothing had changed in my web.config files on either the client or the server. The weird thing was, I could still hit my endpoints from a browser and they all worked just fine but for some reason, the mex didn't like something. Google searches proved to be of no use since there was nothing wrong with my configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I browsed to `http:localhost/MyService.svc`, I was presented with the following error:

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
 contract: http://tempuri.org/:IAdministrationService ----> System.InvalidOperationException: The IMyService1.UpdatePartner operation references a message element [http://tempuri.org/:UpdatePartner] that has already been exported from the IMyService2.UpdatePartner operation. You can change the name of one of the operations by changing the method name or using the Name property of OperationContractAttribute. Alternatively, you can control the element name in greater detail using the MessageContract programming model.
```

While I do indeed have two functions called UpdatePartner, one of them takes in a User_Partner object as a parameter and the other takes in a Partner object (which corresponded to one of my newly-created tables). Essentially, this is just an overloaded method so it happily compiled in Visual Studio. I'll be honest, I'm not entirely sure what goes on behind-the-scenes with WCF but my best guess is it converted the parameters to some kind of JSON stream, after which both functions appeared to have the same signature. Removing one of the functions resolved the issue. I assume I also could have renamed one but in my case, the version that took in an User_Partner was obsolete and no longer needed.